# How to read data from binary file in dynamic array in C

Tags: c, arrays, dynamic, data-structures, binaryfiles

In the following code, I try to read data from a binary file and write it into a dynamic array.

The function "getAnz" should give me the numbers of datasets.

In the function "readRecs", I want to read the data from the binary file and write it into a dynamic array (zArr).

The programm gives me the correct number of datasets. Yeah.

Now I have few question:

1. What's wrong the way I read the data and write it into the dynamic array?

2. How do I pass "zArr" from the main function to the readRecs function?

3. Is there another, easier way to get the number of datasets in the file?

Thanks for your help.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct daten
{
    char name[20];
    int alter;
};

long getAnz(FILE *fp)
{
    struct daten ptr;
    long counter = 0;

    while(fread(&ptr, sizeof(struct daten), 1, fp))
    {
        counter++;
    }

    fclose(fp);

    return counter;
}

void foo(FILE *fp, struct daten *zArr[], long lAnz)
{
    long i = 0;

    for(i = 0;i < lAnz;i++)
    {
        if(i == 0)
        {
             zArr = malloc(sizeof(*zArr));
        }
        else
        {
            zArr = realloc(zArr,sizeof(*zArr)*(i+1));
        }   
    }

    fclose(fp);
}

int main(void)
{
    struct daten *zArr;
    long anz = 0, i = 0;

    FILE *fp = fopen("daten.bin", "rb");
    anz = getAnz(fp);
    printf("%ld\n", anz);
    foo(fp, &zArr, anz);

    for(i = 0; i<anz; i++)
    {
        printf("%s\t", zArr[i].name);
        printf("%d\n", zArr[i].alter);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Among other problems you are passing by value the pointer `zArr` to `void foo(FILE *fp, struct daten *zArr[], long lAnz)` so its change is scoped within the function. if you want the changes to persist once foo returns try `void foo(FILE *fp, struct daten * &zArr, long lAnz)`

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://code.google.com/p/c-cgi-lib/source/browse/lib/getfile.c) I did dynamic read like that:

```
ssize_t mygetline(char **buffer, int fd){
        size_t bufportion = 16000, bufsz = bufportion, i = 0;
        free(*buffer); *buffer = NULL;
        char *ptr;
        char *buf;
        buf = malloc(bufsz);
        if(!buf){freeQS(); die(MEMERR);}
        ptr = buf;
        if(read(fd, ptr, 1) != 1){ free(buf); return -1; }
        do{
                if(*ptr == '\n' || *ptr == 0) break;
                ptr++;
                if(++i >= bufsz){
                        bufsz += bufportion;
                        buf = realloc(buf, bufsz);
                        if(!buf){freeQS(); die(MEMERR);}
                        ptr = &buf[i];
                }
        }while(read(fd, ptr, 1) == 1);
        *ptr = 0;
        if(ptr > buf && *(ptr-1) == '\r') *(ptr-1) = 0;
        *buffer = strdup(buf);
        free(buf);
        return strlen(*buffer);
}
```

In your code above there's no operation of filling array with data.

Comment: sorry, but this doesn't help me. Could you specific explain what's wrong in my code and what I need to correct?

Comment: I give you an example. First, you can simultaneously fill array with data and count data length. Second, if we'll return to your code, int `getAnz` there's no need to read data by one portion, you can read more (of course input buffer should be larger). Function `foo` do something weird: if you **know** data size, why are you call `realloc` and so much times? And this function doesn't do its main work: filling data array. BTW, you close your file **twice**.